# Loop through nested json array object and sum values javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js

I would like to create a new object with OrgID, Name and Value with unique OrgID.

Data:

```
{
    "id":0,
    "Value": "12345"
    "Organisations"
    {
        "OrgID": "1",
        "Name": "A"
    }
},
{
    "id":1,
    "Value": "74790"
    "Organisations"
    {
        "OrgID": "1",
        "Name": "A"
    }
},  {
    "id":2,
    "Value": "89668"
    "Organisations"
    {
        "OrgID": "2",
        "Name": "C"
    }
},
{
    "id":3,
    "Value": "23559"
    "Organisations"
    {
        "OrgID": "3",
        "Name": "D"
    }
}
```

For below example: sum of id 0 and 1 should occur, and 3rd and 4th id as it is.

```
Final Object = [
{1, A, 94521},
{2, C, 75463},
{3, D, 56743}
];
```

I tried using nested for loops and reduce. But I am unable to get results I need.

```
var result = Array.from(
    data.reduce((organisations, obj) =>
        organisations.set(obj.organisations.Name,
            (organisations.get(obj.organisations.Name) || 0) + +obj.Value),
        new Map()),
    ([organ, sum]) => ({organ,sum})
);
```

Comment: Your `Final Object` array does not contain proper JS objects.

Comment: That is just an example. but I will be having an array of objects with 3 elements

Comment: I just want a way to go one level down to check the id and then sum the values accordingly.

Comment: I think the lack of answers stem from the fact that both the input data and the expected output is totally invalid in any language? Anyway -> **https://jsfiddle.net/evy0keo6/**

Comment: + +obj.Value. does. I myself dont understand the code therefore, I prefer something that I understand. code was given in practice tutorial. Please suggest something outside the box. I am open to different solutions.

Comment: @adeneo Yes, it does work, but How can I get organisations.Name in an array object? i can see OrgName and Value but no OrgID. Its not in your tree aswell.

Comment: The `OrgID` is the key, I made an object, as the thing you posted as an example of what should be returned is total hogwash.

Comment: Your data object has errors. Try using JSONlint.com to help you format your data next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, is it desired result?

```js
var data = [
  {
    "id":0,
    "Value": "12345",
    "Organisations":
    {
        "OrgID": "1",
        "Name": "A"
    }
},
{
    "id":1,
    "Value": "74790",
    "Organisations":
    {
        "OrgID": "1",
        "Name": "A"
    }
},  {
    "id":2,
    "Value": "89668",
    "Organisations":
    {
        "OrgID": "2",
        "Name": "C"
    }
},
{
    "id":3,
    "Value": "23559",
    "Organisations":
    {
        "OrgID": "3",
        "Name": "D"
    }
}
];

var res = {};

res = Object.keys(data.reduce((res, curr) => {
  res[curr.Organisations.OrgID] = res[curr.Organisations.OrgID] || {
    OrgID: curr.Organisations.OrgID,
    Name: curr.Organisations.Name,
    Value: 0
  };
  res[curr.Organisations.OrgID].Value += parseInt(curr.Value);
  return res;
}, res)).map(key => res[key]);

console.log(res);
```